# ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=v1 API cannot be used to access GKE regional clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes

This tutorial of Google Kubernetes Engine seems not to work.

> https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters create hello-cluster --num-nodes=3
WARNING: You invoked `gcloud beta`, but with current configuration Kubernetes Engine v1 API will be used instead of v1beta1 API.
`gcloud beta` will switch to use Kubernetes Engine v1beta1 API by default by the end of March 2018.
If you want to keep using `gcloud beta` to talk to v1 API temporarily, please set `container/use_v1_api` property to true.
But we will drop the support for this property at the beginning of May 2018, please migrate if necessary.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=v1 API cannot be used to access GKE regional clusters. See http:/goo.gl/Vykvt2 for more information.
```

It seems this command request `GKE regional clusters` but I have no idea how to stop it.

Answer (score 5):

It worked well by adding `--zone=` option.

```
 gcloud container clusters create hello-cluster --num-nodes=3 --zone=asia-northeast1-a
```

You can find a proper zone name with the following command;

```
gcloud compute zones list
```

`NAME` and `REGION` are slightly different. Please remind to use `NAME` to the `--zone=` option.

You can find it in this `Available regions & zones` document also.

> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you specify the "project ID" not the "project name"

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters create hello-cluster --project=project-id --zone=europe-west1-a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Google Kubernetes Engine API.
More : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your zone, region and also enable the Kubernetes API [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster) for your current project before you can use the `gcloud container clusters create` command.

Answer (score -1):

checkout the role of your service account.